# Using pthread in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, parallel-processing, pthreads

I want to run 2 functions at same time in a C program.
after some search i found out that i have to use pthread.
but i don't know how to use it in VS 2013. i found some helps but none of theme works for me and after all of them i got this error:

```
the program can't start because pthreadVC2.dll is missing from your computer. Try re installing the program to fix this problem.
```

By the way is there any other way to run 2 functions like below in parallel way?

```
func1(){
...
}

func2(){
...
}

run( func1(), func2() )
```

Comment: Have you tried Windows threads (CreateThread) or std::thread instead of pthreads? Windows does not support the pthreads natively.

Comment: its not a C++ program dude. can i use std::thread in it? if yes tel me how?

Comment: Use [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) or [beginthreadex_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx). Both of these functions available in C applications in VS 2013

Comment: i dont know how they works

Comment: Here is an example @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx)